# Simplest way to allow posting to a Rails site using MarsEdit/Ecto/etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, xml-rpc

I have a simple site, using restful_authentication and a simple model for the posts. I would like to use [MarsEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MarsEdit) (or something like [Ecto](http://illuminex.com/ecto/)) to post/edit content. How would I go about this?

The XML-RPC system is rather bewildering - there's a lot of different variations (Atom, MovableType, metaWeblog, Blogger, TypePad, probably others), never mind actually implementing any of them.. The Action Web Service API in Rails, which is intended to implement such APIs, has deprecated a while ago..

Answer (score 1):

Try a plugin...

http://github.com/calavera/atompub-server/tree/master

Or this library...

http://github.com/inkspot/alumina/tree/master

As a starter/prototype for what you need